# Powershell: Defining the Verbose switch in a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Referring [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/02/25/supporting-whatif-confirm-verbose-in-scripts.aspx) link, I am trying to introduce verbose mode in my script.

When I have a function defined like this -

```
function TestVerbose
{
    param(
        [switch]$verbose,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] 
        $p1
    )

    if($verbose)
    {
     Write-Verbose "Verbose Mode"
    }
}

Get-Help TestVerbose
```

I get the following error -

> Get-Help : A parameter with the name 'Verbose' was defined multiple
>   times for the command. At line:12 char:9
>   + Get-Help <<<<  TestVerbose
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-Help], MetadataException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterNameAlreadyExistsForCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand

**BUT,** if I define the function like this [removing the parameter mandatory attribute], it works fine

```
function TestVerbose
{
    param(
        [switch]$verbose,
        $p1
    )
    if($verbose)
    {
     Write-Verbose "Verbose Mode"
    }    
}

Get-Help TestVerbose
```

Any idea why such a behaviour ? I want to keep the mandatory switch and want the user to execute my function like this -

> TestVerbose -verbose

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It appears you are using PoweShell v2, in which Verbose (along with debug, whatif, etc) are reserved and their functions automatically provided for you. Instead of writing your own 'verbose' detection switch, the functionality is already there. In the case of verbose you don't have to specify it in the parameter declaration, other parameters likes whatif require special synatax.

```
C:\Users\james> function testverbose{
>>     param(
>>         [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
>>         $bar
>>     )
>>
>>     Write-Verbose "VERBOSE!"
>>     $bar
>> }
>>
C:\Users\james> testverbose -bar "woot"
woot
C:\Users\james> testverbose -bar "woot" -Verbose
VERBOSE: VERBOSE!
woot
```

Comment: Thanks ! Did not know this. Yes, I am using V2.

Comment: I still wanted to be able to test to see if the -Verbose switch was activated.  I found my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446680/is-it-possible-to-check-if-verbose-argument-was-given-in-powershell).