# Powershell removing commandlet flag altogether depending on powershell version

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, powershell-7.3

With Powershell 7 there have been several changes to `Invoke-RestMethod`. I've written some modules that are wrappers for several Invoke-RestMethod calls to simplify the interaction with our API for my colleagues. In Powershell 5.1 this code runs fine:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://localhost/MyServer/MyApi" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

In Powershell 7 this generates an error because I'm using an HTTP resource rather than HTTPS:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: The cmdlet cannot protect plain text secrets sent over unencrypted connections. To suppress this warning and send plain text secrets over unencrypted networks, reissue the command specifying the AllowUnencryptedAuthentication parameter.
```

To get around this you just need to add `-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication` to the call and it works, but that only works for Powershell 7. If I add the flag in a Powershell 5.1 environment it generates an error because the flag doesn't exist:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllowUnencryptedAuthentication'.
```

There is a workaround by doing the following, but making this change to every single module is going to be a PITA since the `Invoke-RestMethod` varies from module to module:

```
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -gt 5) {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://localhost/MyServer/MyApi" -UseDefaultCredentials -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication
}
else {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "http://localhost/MyServer/MyApi" -UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

I know that you can pass values like `-Verbose` using something like `$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Verbose"].IsPresent` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446680/is-it-possible-to-check-if-verbose-argument-was-given-in-powershell) but I need to completely remove the flag if I'm in a 5.1 or earlier environment and add it for 7 or later. Is there a way to do this in one line or do I need to make the above change to every module?

Comment: Maybe `if($IsCoreCLR) { $PSDefaultParameterValues['Invoke-RestMethod:AllowUnencryptedAuthentication'] = $true }` then you don't need a condition for Windows PowerShell

Comment: Holy, this is amazing, I had no idea you could specify default parameters like this! This opens up a lot of other opportunities, thank you so much! If you post this as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: You can also build a hashtable of parameters and "splat" them for a specific call to a cmdlet - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3 - similar to @SantiagoSquarzon's comment you just detect the powershell version and add keys to the hashtable as appropriate.

Comment: Ah, yeah you mean like if $IsCoreCLR I add it to the hast table, and for the final step in all my modules I just splat them for that call? That might actually be helpful in other ways too for me, thanks!

Comment: @TanakaSaito I added mclayton's approach to my answer for reference tho I believe you already understood how it would go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using only one condition that checks if the version is PowerShell Core, and if it is, add `AllowUnencryptedAuthentication = $true` as default value using the preference variable [`$PSDefaultParameterValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
if($IsCoreCLR) {
    $PSDefaultParameterValues['Invoke-RestMethod:AllowUnencryptedAuthentication'] = $true
}
```

A simple example using a temporary module with an advanced function:

```bash
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    'Test-PSDefaultParameterValues:param1' = 'hello'
    'Test-PSDefaultParameterValues:param2' = 'world!'
}

New-Module -Name temp -ScriptBlock {
    function Test-PSDefaultParameterValues {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param($param1, $param2)

        "$param1 $param2"
    }
} -Function Test-PSDefaultParameterValues | Import-Module

Test-PSDefaultParameterValues
```

You could also use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3) as [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) pointed out in a comment. This way would be preferable in my opinion instead of updating the session state of a possible user of your module, however this would also need to be updated in all your function calls:

```bash
# this would be the default params for calling the cmdlet
$param = @{
    Method = 'Get'
    Uri    = 'http://localhost/MyServer/MyApi'
    UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}

# then we check if this is Core, and then add the missing
# parameter to the splat hashtable
if($IsCoreCLR) {
    $param['AllowUnencryptedAuthentication'] = $true
}

Invoke-RestMethod @param
```

Comment: Thanks for adding both answers! I'm having some serious consideration of moving to splatting because that will mean my error handling/printing becomes much easier to deal with (as I can print things like $Body or $URI when I modify them, error messages would be identical in code). Very helpful!

Comment: @TanakaSaito indeed, you would also avoid updating the session state of a potential user. `$PSDefaultParameterValues` is great, not gonna lie, but should in an ideal world, be used for personal purposes and not be included as part of a module requirement